# How to use andWhere in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Does anybody know how to use the andWhere() condition in yii. I'm getting the below error when i use it.

```
CDbCommand and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "andWhere".
```

here is sample code

```
 $result=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select()
->from('{{product}}')
->andWhere('price>:param1', array(':param1'=>150))
->andWhere('price<:param2', array(':param2'=>210))
->queryAll();
```

Comment: Can you add the code snippet where you're trying to use it?

Comment: yes , i added some sample code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`andWhere()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#andWhere-detail) function is added in yii 1.1.13. It seems you are using older version of yii. Update the framework

Comment: How to update it, i'm using 1.1.10 currently

Comment: download latest version from http://yiiframework.com/ and update. Make changes to your code accoring to the http://static.yiiframework.com/files/UPGRADE-1.1.13.txt

Answer (score -1):

how about trying this method , it's a easy peazy

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
       ->select("*")
       ->from('package')
       ->where('id=:id and status:status', array(':id'=>5,':status'=>1))
       ->queryRow();
```

or even

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition = 'id=:id and status=:status';
    $criteria->params = array(':id'=>$id,':status'=>1);
```

to be exact

```
$result=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
   ->select()
   ->from('{{product}}')
   ->where('price>:param1 and price<:param2', array(':param1'=>150,':param2'=>210))
   ->queryAll();
```

Comment: At some point between copying and pasting, you should have realized that this code has no relation to what the OP asks.

Comment: i was givin examples bro !

Comment: *Unrelated* examples.

Comment: how about this? [see edit]