# How to use IN/AND clause in Yii framework?

Tags: mysql-error-1064, yii

I have a MySQL table with 3 columns: ID, name, user. 
I wish to use the following SQL with Yii framework:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE idName=".$name." AND user IN .$arrayOfUsers;
// $arrayOfUsers is an array of int [0]->1, etc.
```

I tried in three different ways, but without success:

1)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE idName=".$name." AND user IN .$arrayOfUsers;
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);            
$dataReader = $command->query();          
$query = $dataReader->readAll();
```

The error is:

> ## PHP Error [8]
>
> Array to string conversion

2)

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('my_table')
    ->where(array('and', array('in', 'user', $arrayOfUsers), array('idName' => $name)))
    ->queryAll();
```

The error is:

> ## PHP Error [8]
>
> Undefined offset: 0

3)

```
 $query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('my_table')
        ->where(array('and', array('in', 'user', $arrayOfUsers), 'idName='.$name)))
        ->queryAll();
```

The error is:

> ## CDbException
>
> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL
>   statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'idName=7)'
>   at line 3. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM
>   `my_table` WHERE (`user` IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')) AND
>   (idName=7)

Comment: I am sorry, but I think it is not a Yii issue, but probably is a MySQL issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = "*";
$criteria->condition = "idname = :name ";
$criteria->params = array ( 
':name' => $name,
);
$criteria->addInCondition('user', $arrayOfUsers);
my_table::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: <h1>CDbException</h1>
<p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'idName= '7' ) AND (user IN ('1', '2', '3', '4'))' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `my_table` `t` WHERE (idName= :idName ) AND (user IN (:ycp0, :ycp1, :ycp2, :ycp3))

Comment: idname field is an integer or an varchar ?

Comment: Does your simple sql query you posted above without using yii executes properly ?

Comment: I tried to type in phpmyadmin this query: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE idName=7 AND user IN (1,2,3,4)
and I have the same error! Why?
Furthermore, phpmyadmin says:
_The column name 'idName' is a MySQL reserved keyword._
Can be that the problem?

Comment: yes that is the main problem fix that first and then try it in yii

Answer (score 12):

There has many ways to do but I'd like to use Active Record to handle this thing.
However, your question was around Query Builder, I give you correct one

Edited: (As your comment, idName is big INT instead of var char)

1) You got error because you pass `$arrayOfUsers` which was array, not expected string on your sql. It should be

```
 $connection=Yii::app()->db;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE idName=".$name." AND (user IN(".implode(',',$arrayOfUsers)."))";
        $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
        $query = $command->queryAll();
```

2) Using `Query builder` and `where operator`

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('*')
            ->from('my_table')
            ->where(array('in', 'user', $arrayOfUsers))
            ->andwhere('name = :name', array('idName'=>$name))
            ->queryAll();
```

3) If you want to wrap them together, it'll be fine, but they look unsightly like this

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('*')
            ->from('my_table')
            ->where(array('and', 'idName= ' . $name, array('in', 'user', $arrayOfUsers)))
            ->queryAll();
```

More references how to use `where operator` from official document

```
// WHERE id=1 or id=2
where('id=1 or id=2')
// WHERE id=:id1 or id=:id2
where('id=:id1 or id=:id2', array(':id1'=>1, ':id2'=>2))
// WHERE id=1 OR id=2
where(array('or', 'id=1', 'id=2'))
// WHERE id=1 AND (type=2 OR type=3)
where(array('and', 'id=1', array('or', 'type=2', 'type=3')))
// WHERE `id` IN (1, 2)
where(array('in', 'id', array(1, 2))
// WHERE `id` NOT IN (1, 2)
where(array('not in', 'id', array(1,2)))
// WHERE `name` LIKE '%Qiang%'
where(array('like', 'name', '%Qiang%'))
// WHERE `name` LIKE '%Qiang' AND `name` LIKE '%Xue'
where(array('like', 'name', array('%Qiang', '%Xue')))
// WHERE `name` LIKE '%Qiang' OR `name` LIKE '%Xue'
where(array('or like', 'name', array('%Qiang', '%Xue')))
// WHERE `name` NOT LIKE '%Qiang%'
where(array('not like', 'name', '%Qiang%'))
// WHERE `name` NOT LIKE '%Qiang%' OR `name` NOT LIKE '%Xue%'
where(array('or not like', 'name', array('%Qiang%', '%Xue%')))
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

Comment: 1)
<h1>CException</h1>
<p>CDbCommand and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "andwhere".
<br/>
2)
<h1>CDbException</h1>
<p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'idName= "7") AND (`user` IN ('1', '2', '3', '4'))' at line 3. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE (idName= "7") AND (`user` IN ('1', '2', '3', '4'))

Comment: The andWhere() function is added in yii 1.1.13. It seems you are using older version of yii. Update the framework or you can try my solution 1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004419/how-to-use-andwhere-in-yii?answertab=active#tab-top